# Compiling and installing a simple binary using Ansible

Tags: compilation, ansible

Say I have a very simple program `magic_command.c` that I want compiled to `magic_command` and installed in `/usr/local/bin`.

One method I can think of for doing this is roughly the following with Ansible:

- Create a temporary directory on the remote host
- Copy the `magic_command.c` and a `Makefile` to the temporary directory
- Run `make all` to create `magic_command`
- Run `make install`, a target that copies `magic_command` to `/usr/local/bin`

Is there a simpler or more concise way of doing this with Ansible?

Comment: http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/5778

Comment: @techraf Not sure how that's relevant - "Without code embedded directly within the question, we just cannot do a Code Review."

Comment: That's a good point. Your question not only requests subjective answers ("*elegant*"), but is also hypothetical and lacks the code.

Comment: Updated to remove "elegant"; hopefully "simpler" and "more concise" are objective enough for this purpose. I think you'll find a lot of questions on StackOverflow lack code; I am however, asking how to do this using code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using a method very similar to that described in my original question:

```
- name: Create temporary directory for compilation
  command: mktemp -d /tmp/magic_command.XXXXXXXXX
  register: magic_command_temp_dir

- name: Copy source and makefile
  copy: src={{ item }} dest={{ magic_command_temp_dir.stdout }}
  with_items:
    - magic_command.c
    - Makefile

- name: Compile executable
  shell: make chdir={{ magic_command_temp_dir.stdout }}

- name: Install executable
  copy: remote_src=True src={{ magic_command_temp_dir.stdout }}/magic_command dest=/usr/local/bin/magic_command mode=0755 owner=root group=root

- name: Remove temporary directory
  file: name={{ magic_command_temp_dir.stdout }} state=absent
```